# Is there any way to hook up a process to a software diagram for custom analysis?

Tags: c#

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. Plan a process using a custom flow chart (That anyone could write without following any UML standards - just a very basic flow chart). Important to note here this would not be an application with a UI rather a server process, such as a scheduled task or a windows service. Also important to note, connectors in the diagram should be accurate between objects (You'll see why in step 5).
2. Write the code with a 1:1 mapping of objects in my flow charts to function calls. This can be done if the planning of the application is correct.
3. Create a console application from the code, at the same time (somehow) mark in the code what code blocks / function calls relate to which objects in the diagram.
4. Open and (somehow) attach a special type of diagram viewing software, that can also wait for instructions from app (perhaps via port logging).
5. Run the app - watch the diagram. It should at this point be as visual as a workflow. You should be able to follow the flow of the app - and check additional logging perhaps in a side window.

Does such a tool exist for Microsoft related technologies such as c#?

EDIT: Sorry if this isn't code related (per say), feel free to move the question to a more suitable home if needed.

EDIT 2: One use I can see from this is code coverage statistics based on runtime usage. It would also be able to show you where your major bottle necks are (time wise) in SOA applications. It would give you a better view code and you could see (via a map / the diagram) exactly where errors occur, making problems easier to pinpoint.

Comment: This sounds like a crazy morph of the workflow foundation...

Comment: @Gleno - Workflow dictates the way you have to code and you code around activities.
This would be more focused on harnessing your existing coding practices and mapping it to a diagram you created using just a standard flow chart (I have to stress no uml). And the idea is to incorporate planning - but the diagram later serves a purpose for debugging, and statistical analysis.

Obbiously the value really shines when you're developing complex SOA applications talking to many inter dependent systems.

Comment: Hm, actually I've once heard something like this mentioned on Cloud9. There are tools (All I remember is that the video was about ASP.NET debugging, and how in .NET 4.5 it's possible to re-jit methods) that inject IL into compiled C# methods to log function calls. The idea of the video was to show that re-jiting could enable these tools to inject more code if the service was misbehaving, they also mentioned that the tools cost a lot of monies, but to my knowledge no names. Something like : http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/